# Heat-shrinking vinyl

Tags: plastic, heat-treatment

I want to make a vinyl stencil on a curved surface. I already use vinyl stencils with a vector cutter like Silhouette to make designs on flat surfaces. I also use heat-shrinking tape for insulating a repair of electric cables. So I suppose a combination of both exists and I can cut a heat-shrinking vinyl, glue on a curved surface, and apply heat for it to adhere seamlessly to the surface.

What is the name of such material?

Comment: Check out the plastic wrap used on cars - that is used on curves in 3 dimensions...

Comment: Does it have to be vinyl? Model airplanes use this process to apply skins to wood framed wings. It's called "covering", like Monokote. Just any sheet of shrink wrap with a pre-applied adhesive really.

Comment: @DKNguyen, your comment is suitable to become an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be vinyl? Model airplanes use this process to apply skins to wood framed wings. It's called "covering film", like Monokote. Just any sheet of shrink wrap with a pre-applied adhesive really.